# Android - Programmatic Ringtone update on Incoming call not working properly the first time

Tags: android, ringtone

I am getting the following warning message when am calling RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri method to set the new ringtone on incoming call and the old ringtone got played this time but the new ringtone got updated in the back and is played next time.

> W/BackupManagerService(61): dataChanged but no participant pkg='com.android.providers.settings' uid=10037

**Call Listener**

```
class MyCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {

Uri newUri = null;
Uri oldUri = null;

Context context;

public MyCallListener(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
    Log.i("RandomRingtone:CallListener", "State : " + state);
    Log.i("RandomRingtone:CallListener", "IncomingNumber : "
            + incomingNumber);

    switch (state) {
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
        Log.i("RandomRingtone:CallListener", "Changing Ringtone");
        Log.i("RandomRingtone:CallListener",
                "Old Ringtone : "
                        + RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                                context, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE));
        File k = new File("/sdcard/", "01 - Chinna Chinna.mp3");
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "My Song title");
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mpeg");
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "Some Artist");
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k
                .getAbsolutePath());
        // Line below is major because we need to delete old entry
        context.getContentResolver().delete(
                uri,
                MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + k.getAbsolutePath()
                        + "\"", null);
        newUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
        oldUri = RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context,
                RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
        // On call you replace the ringtone with your own mUri
        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context,
                RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
        // Settings.System.putString(context.getContentResolver(),
        // Settings.System.RINGTONE, newUri.toString());
        Log.i("RandomRingtone:CallListener",
                "New Ringtone : "
                        + RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                                context, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE));

        break;
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
        Log.i("RandomRingtone:CallListener", "Restore the default ringtone");
        Log.i("RandomRingtone:CallListener",
                "Old Ringtone : "
                        + RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                                context, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE));

        // Restore the default ringtone
        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context,
                RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, oldUri);
        // Settings.System.putString(context.getContentResolver(),
        // Settings.System.RINGTONE, oldUri.toString());
        Log.i("RandomRingtone:CallListener",
                "New Ringtone : "
                        + RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                                context, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE));
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
}
}
```

**Broadcast Receiver**

```
public class StartServicesAtStartUp extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.w("DEBUG", "StartServicesAtStartUp");
    TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    MyCallListener callListener = new MyCallListener(context);
    mTelephonyMgr
            .listen(callListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    Log.w("DEBUG", "Call Listener Added....");
}
}
```

**Android Manifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.randomringtone"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <!--        <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".RandomRingtoneActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>  -->

    <!--
    <receiver android:name="MyPhoneReceiver" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    -->
    <receiver android:name="StartServicesAtStartUp" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
</manifest>
```

I am stuck in this issue. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Deepak

Comment: have you find anything to do this ?? if yes, please  share it, i want to do the exactly same thing.